# RepositoryEventHandler HandleAfterLinkDelete access to unlinked object

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I couldn't find any documentation but I wonder if it is possible to access the unlinked object in the link event handler? Upon debugging, it is a proxy object but why pass it as parameter if it's not accessible.

```
@HandleAfterLinkDelete
public void handleAfterUnlinked(Entity entity, Object unlinked) {
    //unlinked is a proxy object
}
```

or even in the before handler

```
@HandleBeforeLinkDelete
public void handleBeforeUnlinked(Entity entity, Object unlinked) {
    //unlinked is a proxy object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd parameter will be a `Proxy` instance whose underlying object  will be an instance of `Collection` of the type of the associated field. The unlinked (in case of the Delete events) or the linked object (in the case of the Save events) can be accessed by casting the second parameter to a collection and getting its content.

If the `Entity` class as a collection property of type X, you could use:

```java
@HandleAfterLinkDelete
public void handleAfterUnlinked(Entity entity, Object unlinked) {
    if (unlinked instanceof Collection) {
        Collection unlinkedCollection = (Collection) unlinked;
        // use the collection
    }
}
```

Note that there is not reference to the specific object that was unlinked (or the object that is linked, for the LinkSaved events). That appears like a bug in the Spring Data implementation.

Comment: It seems that the unlinked object (second parameter) does include the reference but to the entity's linked items in the AfterLinkDelete event, however, I was keen on getting the reference to the unlinked items from that event. It's useful info tho, thank you!