# spring RepositoryEventHandler for link modification missing link target reference

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am using a `RepositoryRestController` to expose REST endpoint to modify entity `X` which is linked to another entity Y.

```java
class X {
    Set<Y> y_set;
}
```

I would like to execute some code when `Y`s are added or removed to an `X`.

```java
class MyAction {
    // initialised somehow
    XRepository xRepo;

    public void unlinkYFromX() {
       X x = xRepo.getAnX();
       // get a Y from the ones linked to X using some logic
       Y y = x.getYs().get(0);
       x.getYs().delete(y);
       xRepo.save(x);
       // I expect the event handlers to be trigger now
       // giving me a reference to x and y 
    }

}
```

I am trying to define a `RepositoryEventHandler` with a handler function annotated with `HandleBeforeLinkSave`:

```java
@RepositoryEventHandler
class XYLinkHandler {

@HandleBeforeLinkSave
 public void handleYLinkSave(X x, Object linked) {
        // do some code with the source X
        // and the newly linked Y
    }
}
```

The problem is that the 2nd argument of the handler function is always null. In other words it does not contain the `Y` I am linking.

The same phenomenon (missing linked reference) happens regardless if it a Before, After, Save or Delete event handler.

Has anyone encountered this problem?
Does anyone have a solution or workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any chance you can prepare a simple reproducer and file an issue? I've just done some work in that area to improve the ability to select which linked objects you're interested in. Currently, you should see the full value of the property (single object or collection) handed into the method, if you declare it to accept `Object` for the linked element.

Comment: Thanks, @OliverDrotbohm, for taking the time and effort to investigate. Do you mean that if the parent entity  `X` references a set with 2 child entities `Y`, and I add another `Y` to the set or remove a `Y` from the set, I should be getting the added or deleted `Y` element in the `linked` parameter? In my tests, this does not happen. The `linked` parameter always holds a proxy to an empty object.

Comment: Nope. You should see value of the property of `X` that holds the `Y`s. The code triggering the events is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/main/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java#L304). As you can see, the `linked`attribute of the event is getting the property value passed. That in turn should be initialized and have gotten the submitted values bound.

Comment: Let's say I need to do something on the Y that was unlinked from X. How could I do it? I added the scenario to the description.

Comment: Are you saying that the event handlers get the X instance I modified and the `y_set` `Set` object? And that the *before* event would contain the y_set before the deletion and the *after* event would get its content after the deletion?

Comment: Is there any chance you could jump on our [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-data) (feel free to ping me 1:1 there)? I'd love to understand what you're looking for, whether we might already support that or could with additions to the feature coming up, but feel like we're abusing the comments here for that .

Comment: @OliverDrotbohm Here is the problem with the code you linked. It creates event before saving entity, but after it got modified. So there is no way to figure out what links was added or deleted. For example if `X` had only one link to `Y`, and there is request to delete such association, the event will come with empty `PersistentBag`. I think event should  contain a bag of entities requested to delete or add, that we could process them separately.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter, `linked`, is a `Proxy` object to the collection property. It contains the entire contents, not just the newly added (or removed) object. It could be used by casting it to a `Collection` and working on the collection. This, appears a buggy implementation, since the inability to know which item is added to the collection makes this event handler rather limited in its capability.

See a workaround [in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267460/repositoryeventhandler-handleafterlinkdelete-access-to-unlinked-object)